# Molecular Docking physiological effects

Tags: equilibrium

If I wanted to perform a Virtual Screening for one molecule and several ligands, take for example, the docking between TDO protein and several antidepressant drugs:

How would I be able to correlate the docking affinity with a physiological effect?

Is it necessary to perform clinical studies also?

I think this question could be extrapolated to many cases of MD, but let's take the molecules discussed as an example. TDO catalyzes the oxidation of L-tryptophan (L-Trp) to N-formyl-L-kynurenine, as the first and rate-limiting step of the kynurenine pathway. It is an enzyme, and as such a molecule with a high docking affinity would probably inhibit it´s action.

But what if the molecule was a membrane transporter? How could we determine if the binding to a ligand prevents the binding of the receptor, or on the contrary favors it?

PS: Not sure if this question belongs to this forum, if it´s more suitable in bioinformatics or another let me know.

Comment: You need to know of course if your molecular simulations are accurate (whether they reflect what happens in the organism), but you would also need a biochemical model of the target's function and how processes at the cellular/tissue/organ level relate to a response at the organism level.

Comment: Regarding your second example (about transporters) you might want to be more specific regarding what receptor you are referring to. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: @BuckThorn thx a lot for your answer. I guess I could know if my simulations are accurate based on the scoring function?  But how do I connect this with the physiological effect, how can I get a biochemical model of the target´s function? is there a way of doing this in silico? I want to perform a MD for TrkB, this receptor interacts with BDNF, so performing MD doesn´t really achieve anything if I can´t explain whether this docking would inhibit the interaction between this two molecules, or, in the contrary, enhance it

Comment: You would need to compare experimental (in vitro presumably) data to simulations to see if your scoring functions are accurate. You might use relative scoring functions, either way experimental reference data would be important. I would not know how to set up a model to predict binding effects (I can imagine how it might work but it is not my specialty).

Comment: This article deals with the interaction network of TrkB: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3889250/

Comment: Regarding your question on whether binding of a small molecule interferes or enhances binding of TrkB to BDNF, you might start from a model with or without the small molecule and compare docking of BDNF to this.

Comment: @BuckThorn thx again for your answer, really appreciated. I think I´ll find a reasonable way to establish a connection between previous experimental data and my MD results. Regarding the TrkB molecular interaction network, however, I could not find a way to link this information and my study. Isn't that a little out of the reach of a virtual screening?

Comment: I know too little about your specific system to answer on how to link these but a true expert on this would be able to tell you (I'm guessing since you are running such sims you'd be able to).

Comment: @BuckThorn I think the interactome may influence the criteria to consider in order to choose an appropiate crystalline structure. That is, it´s conformation, maybe even pH.. I will take all that into consideration. Really appreciated, it was helpful